# Task Module empty although

Tags: c#, botframework, url-routing, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

so I created a chat bot which is sending adaptive cards. Those cards contain buttons which start task modules. But the module is empty (see picture).
[Empty Task Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVdw8.jpg)
The behaviour in web is slightly different.

The bot messaging endpoint is https://xxx.westeurope.azurecontainer.io/api/messages and working fine. So I added "xxx.westeurope.azurecontainer.io" to the validDomains array in the manifest json. Furthermore the bot's OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync is looking like this:

```
protected override Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.FromResult(new TaskModuleResponse
    {
        Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
        {
            Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo
            {
                Url = "https://xxx.westeurope.azurecontainer.io/api/messages/player",
                Title = "Blanky blank",
                Height = "medium",
                Width = "medium",
                FallbackUrl = "https://xxx.westeurope.azurecontainer.io/api/messages/player"
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I created an endpoint /api/messages/player works perfectly fine in the browser. Upon opening the url the desired view will be displayed. But not within teams (or their web app). Still an empty Task Module.

Endpoint

```
    [HttpGet("player")]
    public IActionResult Player()
    {
        var html = $"<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"https://xxx.westeurope.azurecontainer.io/api/messages/test" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe>";
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = html,
            ContentType = "text/html"
        };
    }
```

In the browser there is some kind of window being displayed in the background. Furthermore the iframe as well as the src (a HLS STreaming link and the corresponding audio content) are being loaded.
[image: iframe loading]
The curious thing: a co-worker had the audio-player even being displayed and the file being played for some seconds (in web), until the service worker timed out
Console ist throwing some warnings/errors i dont understand. they dont seem to be in my code.
[image: console logs]
The curious thing: a co-worker had the audio-player even being displayed and the file being played for some seconds (in web), until the service worker timed out
[image: service worker timing out]

Edit: Working perfectly under teams mobile app. like wtf?! 4 different plattforms, 4 different results. from "not working at all" to "working fine" and everything inbetween.

Edit 2: Still nothing being displayed, but the audio stream is being played in the background (only for teams app). Web still not working, mobile app working as intended.

Edit 3: Tried to open the provided deep link to open a task module, nothing happening in browser/desktop app. not even opening a task module. only, if i exchange the app-id part for my own app id.. but then task module is empty. Console logs:
[image: Console logs for deep link sample]

Edit 4: I tried the following links, on mobile and desktop (Chrome, Windows, Mac), by implementing an OpenUrl-Action-Button as well as by clicking on the link (mostly same  results with both methods). These are the results:

**Test 1:**

APP_ID: ca6614d0-7043-42c2-a18f-1122b9b22b07

URL: https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY

link: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/ca6614d0-7043-42c2-a18f-1122b9b22b07?url=https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY&height=medium&width=medium&title=one

Mobile: Working as intended

Desktop: Nothing happening when clicking on the deeplink. Teams freezing after using the OpenURL-Action-Button. Need to terminate teams via task manager for Windows and Mac.

**Test 2:**

APP_ID: 8a436b11-631e-4edd-8466-76739228097f

URL: https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY

link: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/8a436b11-631e-4edd-8466-76739228097f?url=https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY&height=medium&width=medium&title=one

(*.youtube.com entered in manifest)
Mobile: Working as intended

Desktop: Empty Task Module. Only Title and App-Name displayed. No YT-Video. But Teams NOT freezing.

**Test 3:**

APP_ID: 8a436b11-631e-4edd-8466-76739228097f

URL: Any Website you wish and add to manifest

link: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/8a436b11-631e-4edd-8466-76739228097f?url=ANY_WEBSITE_AS_LONG_AS_MENTIONED_IN_MANIFEST&height=medium&width=medium&title=one

Mobile: Working as intended

Desktop: Empty Task Module. Only Title and App-Name displayed. No Website.

**Versions**

Mobile: iOS v15.5, Teams v4.10.1

Desktop: Windows v10.0.19043, Teams v1.5.00.14473

Chrome: v103.0.5060.53

Mac: iOS v12.3.1, Teams v1.5.00.11157

Comment: It should just be `"BaseUrl/cshtml-file"`. By the way, what OS are you using?

Comment: @AP01 Windows 10. I adjusted the code, created a simple html file and saved it in the pages folder. Furthermore I adjusted the URL to "https://xxx.westeurope.azurecontainer.io" + "/" + "Exercise.html". Still not working. Does the link need to respect the folder structure? Means: "https://xxx.westeurope.azurecontainer.io" + "/pages/" + "Exercise.html"

Comment: Could you test it in the Teams web app?

Comment: @AP01 tested in Teams web app. Worked for a second at a co-workers browser. But not for me. Adjusted the post for more informations.

Comment: @AP01 tested in mobile app. working as intended.

Comment: @Brewcrew-MJ - Could you please refer below thread if its help you in any way: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4186

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT tried the provided code. On mobile App it's working fine. Even if i exchange the URL part. If I change the APP-ID-Part, it won't work... only if i exchange APP-ID and URL-Part of the deep-link.

The desktop and web app freeze, when i click the button to open the deep link. If I exchange the APP-Id-Part, the task module opens but nothing is being displayed. If i exchange APP-Id- and URL Part (for my url), then nothing is being displayed as well, but on desktop app the audio stream is being played in the background.

Comment: @Brewcrew-MJ I too have been having difficulty getting it to work on the Desktop app, so thanks for testing it.

Comment: You might also try downgrading any Bot Builder packages to 4.15.2. Sometimes this works. I'm still trying to figure out what exactly the issue is. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: @Brewcrew-MJ - Could you please update the Teams version and check again? and if you are getting same empty task module please share the console logs?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT did... see edit and screenshot

Comment: @Brewcrew-MJ - Could you please share the deeplink of taskmodule which you are using?

Comment: @Brewcrew-MJ - Are you using below format for deeplink syntax:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/APP_ID?url=<TaskInfo.url>&height=<TaskInfo.height>&width=<TaskInfo.width>&title=<TaskInfo.title>&completionBotId=BOT_APP_ID

Please refer below doc for task module deeplink syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/invoking-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT see my Edit 4. All Links and the different results for the different platforms. Mobile Version allways working perfectly fine.
Again: If I use my streaming url (simple videojs player streaming an HLS file via azure) and  set the player to autoplay, then I can hear the file being played in background, allthough the task module is empty (while eversything is fine on mobile). Hope the in depth test can help to solve this issue.

Comment: @Brewcrew-MJ - Could you please share your sample code zip so we can check this at our end?

Comment: @Brewcrew-MJ - Since we are not able to repro your issue, can you please share your code base, so that we can investigate further on your issue?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft  you got an email adress for me, where I can provide you the sample code in private?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT  you got an email adress for me, where I can provide you the sample code in private?

Comment: Please share it here: microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft sorry for the delay, was on vacation. Just sent you the requested sample code

Comment: @Brewcrew-MJ - We will check this at our end and update you soon.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT see other answer

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft see other answer

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error inside the task module, and that the scenario works on mobile but not on desktop, I think you have [showLoadingIndicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#showloadingindicator) set to true in your manifest, but haven't implemented the corresponding [protocol for showing the loading indicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/content-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2#show-a-native-loading-indicator).

Comment: You, my friend, are the king! Solved the whole problem within 30 seconds!